# Load Street view tiles faster

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have created a tool, in which there are different links for different street views.

But, my client says, when going from one street view to another, some tiles of previous street view doesn't disappear immediately. I told him its normal. I tried to find the solution for it, but there's nothing written to improve the loading time in the documentation. And, couldn't find on any other site/blog.

Can i do something like flash version of Google Maps? In Google Map's flash version it shows the whole street view as blurred image and then loads the tiles one by one. I don't know how to do that in v3 which is based on Javascript. (I'm using Google Maps API v3)